# expressjs download filename utf-8

Tags: node.js, express

express response.download filename is not support utf-8.

I wanna download file, file naming utf-8 (not english)

I already try `Content-Disposition` set to header

like this...

```
res.set "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=테스트 한글.hwp"
```

but not working...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to encode the filename parameter of Content-Disposition header in HTTP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http)

Comment: also see [this](http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/#attwithfn2231utf8).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var newFileName = encodeURIComponent("테스트 한글.hwp");
res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename*=UTF-8\'\''+newFileName);
```

This should do the trick. It helps me with polish diacritics. Note the **=UTF-8\'\'** part.

Comment: Can you please explain to me what does that `UTF-8''` part do?

Comment: It sets HTTP header that tells the browser how to decode filename (which encoding standard is used by the server to send the filename)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
res.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + encodeURI("테스트 한글.hwp"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a popular library for UTF8 encoding/decoding https://www.npmjs.com/package/utf8

```
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename='+utf8.encode(object.pdfFileName));
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/content-disposition

```
res.set("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition("테스트 한글.hwp")
```

```
const {
  parameters: { filename }
} = contentDisposition.parse(resp.headers['content-disposition'])
```